# Error when trying to format datatype NSString to NSMutablestring

Tags: ios, xcode, string, dataformat

I'm doing simple code for Objective-C while i trying to format string type

```
NSMutableString *text;
text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Hello MR. %@",[txtName text]];
lblResponse.text = text;
```

then it said incompatible pointer type assigning,so any solution to solve this ? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are assigning Property of `NSString` to `NSMutableString`

do it like this if you don't want to add something more after this in your string

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Hello MR. %@",[txtName text]];
lblResponse.text = text;
```

Or rather than this, you can simply assing the string to text like this

```
lblResponse.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Hello MR. %@",[txtName text]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lblResponse.text = [NSString stringWithString:YourMutableString];
```

will do the job.